# In AWS SES, can my send region and receive region be different?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

All of my AWS code (API Gateway, Lambda, SQS, EC2, etc) is currently in the Canada Central (ca-central-1) region. I plan to send emails using AWS SES from EC2.

I am trying to enable email receiving in SES using [this guide](https://medium.com/responsetap-engineering/easily-create-email-addresses-for-your-route53-custom-domain-589d099dd0f2), using a custom email address based on my Route 53 domain (e.g. `no-reply@myroute53domain.com`). However I just realized that email receiving is not supported in my region, as it is only supported in [us-east-1, us-west-2, and eu-west-1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ses.html).

According to the [AWS documentation regarding SES regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html) I have to repeat the same processes in every region (e.g. email verification, quota increases, SNS, etc). What is unclear to me is: **If a user replies to an email sent via SES in one region, can that email be received by SES in another region?** That is, if one region (us-east-1) has a rule set passing all emails sent to `no-reply@myroute53domain.com` over to SNS, could that rule set handle replies to emails that were sent from the former (ca-central-1) region?

Or is the only solution for me to send all my emails from (and migrate all my code to) us-east-1?

### Addendum

I also want to confirm that it is not possible to just create `no-reply@myroute53domain.com` for sending via AWS SES. Because to verify the email address, I have to first enable email receiving, right..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If one region (us-east-1) has a rule set passing all emails sent to `no-reply@myroute53domain.com` over to SNS, could that rule set handle replies to emails that were sent from the former (ca-central-1) region?

Yes, where the emails are sent from doesn't matter. If you set up all your SES stuff in us-east-1, when your EC2 located in Canada wants to send an email, in essence, what the EC2 instance will do is that it will connect to either the API endpoint (email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com) or the SMTP endpoint (email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com) located in us-east-1, and pass the email content over to them. Therefore technically speaking, all emails are sent from the SES located in us-east-1.

> I also want to confirm that it is not possible to just create `no-reply@myroute53domain.com` for sending via AWS SES. Because to verify the email address, I have to first enable email receiving, right..?

Since you own the domain name, it's easier to [verify the entire domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/creating-identities.html#verify-domain-procedure) in SES instead of verifying a single email address.

> You can send email from any subdomain or email address of the verified domain without having to verify each one individually.